# Getting individual values using GROUP BY - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table called `lottery_winners` with the following useful colums:

```
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| id | plid | zbid | amount | numbers |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
```

`id` is the unique, primary id for the table. `plid` refers to the `past_lotteries` table (i.e I can get all the lottery winners from a specific lottery in the past this way. `zbid` is the id of the member/user (the winner). `amount` is the sum of money they won in the lottery, and finally `numbers` is a `VARCHAR` CSV field with their lottery numbers.

Here's an example of what rows could be in the table:

```
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| id | plid | zbid | amount | numbers |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | 2    | 1      | 1,2,3   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 2  | 1    | 4    | 5      | 4,5,6   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 3  | 1    | 3    | 7      | 3,4,5   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 4  | 1    | 2    | 3      | 7,8,9   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 5  | 2    | 2    | 8      | 8,9,10  |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
```

Now, I want to run a `SELECT` statement which will bring back all the rows but in a really specific order. The rows should be in grouped by `zbid` as such (in this case I have added a `WHERE plid=1` clause):

```
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| id | plid | zbid | amount | numbers |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | 2    | 1      | 1,2,3   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 4  | 1    | 2    | 3      | 7,8,9   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 2  | 1    | 4    | 5      | 4,5,6   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 3  | 1    | 3    | 7      | 3,4,5   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
```

Next criteria is that not only should they be grouped by `zbid`, but within this grouping they should be ordered by `amount DESC`. This is what it would now look like:

```
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| id | plid | zbid | amount | numbers |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 4  | 1    | 2    | 3      | 7,8,9   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | 2    | 1      | 1,2,3   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 2  | 1    | 4    | 5      | 4,5,6   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
| 3  | 1    | 3    | 7      | 3,4,5   |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+
```

The top two rows have swapped around.

One more criteria. As you can see, although they are grouped by `zbid`, there's no specific order to them. I want it to group by `zbid`, but the order should be based on `sum(amount)` for each group.

The following table shows the totals for each `zbid` in no specific order (taking into account that `plid=1`:

```
+------+-------------+
| zbid | sum(amount) |
+------+-------------+
| 2    | 4           |
+------+-------------+
| 3    | 7           |
+------+-------------+
| 4    | 5           |
+------+-------------+
```

So using this information the final result using the `SELECT` statement should be the following (with an added `sum(amount)` column):

```
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
| id | plid | zbid | amount | numbers | sum(amount) |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 3  | 1    | 3    | 7      | 3,4,5   | 7           |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 2  | 1    | 4    | 5      | 4,5,6   | 5           |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 4  | 1    | 2    | 3      | 7,8,9   | 4           |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
| 1  | 1    | 2    | 1      | 1,2,3   | 4           |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

That's it! Now I've tried a couple of things myself, but I'm not exactly sure how to get the full final result. I have tried:

```
SELECT id,plid,zbid,amount,numbers,sum(amount) FROM lottery_winners GROUP BY zbid ORDER BY sum(amount) DESC
```

Now that seemed to meet the final criterion, but it didn't give me individual results for the table.

Please also note that as these results will be paginated, I will need to be adding `LIMIT $start,$perpage` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have this a try:

```
SELECT  a.id, 
        a.plid, 
        a.zbid,
        a.amount, 
        a.numbers,
        c.totalAmount
FROM    lottery_winners a
            INNER JOIN  (
                            SELECT  b.zbid,
                                    SUM(b.amount) totalAmount
                            FROM    lottery_winner b
                            WHERE   b.plid = 1
                            GROUP BY b.zbid
                        ) c 
                ON a.zbid = c.zbid
WHERE   a.plid = 1
ORDER BY    c.totalAmount desc
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Had to take a look at the `INNER JOIN` for a good 10 minutes as I've never used it before. Is there any way I could add a sort of counter to show which position each `zbid` is in? So the `zbid` who has the highest `totalAmount` would be first etc?